# in magento 2.4.5 data not saved of custom attribute added by db_schema.xml

Tags: magento2

Could someone assist me in resolving this issue? I've created a custom attribute for customers, but when I attempt to save data from the admin panel for any customer, it doesn't get saved.
Here is the details

```
--db_schema.xml
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
        <table name="customer_entity">
            <column xsi:type="varchar" name="dataprivacy_attribute" nullable="true" length="255" comment="Data Privacy Status"/>
        </table>
    </schema>

view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <fieldset name="account_information" sortOrder="50">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Fields</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <field name="dataprivacy_attribute">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">dataprivacy_attribute</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Attribute</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your customer attribute using data patch.

Depending on the type, magento will add it to respective customer eav table. e.g. customer_entity_int, customer_entity_varchar, customer_entity_text etc

If you want add an attribute to the main **customer_entity** table, then you need to add it as a static type.

Refer below code

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

class DataPrivacyAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return DataPatchInterface|void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $eavSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'dataprivacy_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar', // stored in customer_entity_varchar table
                //'type' => 'static', // stored in customer_entity table
                'label' => 'Data Privacy',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 130,
                'visible' => true,
                'position'  => 130,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'system'  => false
            ]
        );

        $dpAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'dataprivacy_attribute');

        $dpAttribute->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer', 
                'customer_account_create', 
                'customer_account_edit'
            ],
        ]);

        $dpAttribute->save();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create the custom customer attribute you have to use the data patch...
you can follow the following steps to create the attributes.

1. To create the customer attribute, please create the **CustomerAttribute.php** file at the following location.
   **app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/Patch/Data/**

   ```
    <?PHP

   namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

   use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCollectionFactory;
   use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
   use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
   use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;
   use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

   class CustomerAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface
      {
      /**
       * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
       */
       private $moduleDataSetup;

       /**
        * @var EavSetupFactory
        */
       private $eavSetupFactory;

       /**
        * @var ProductCollectionFactory
        */
       private $productCollectionFactory;

       /**
        * @var LoggerInterface
        */
       private $logger;

       /**
        * @var Config
        */
       private $eavConfig;

       /**
        * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute
        */
       private $attributeResource;

       /**
        * CustomerAttribute Constructor
        * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
        * @param Config $eavConfig
        * @param LoggerInterface $logger
        * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource
        * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
        */
       public function __construct(
           EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
           Config $eavConfig,
           LoggerInterface $logger,
           \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource,
           \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
       ) {
           $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
           $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
           $this->logger = $logger;
           $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
           $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
       }

       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public function apply()
       {
           $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
           $this->addDataPrivacyAttribute();
           $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
       }

       /**
        * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException
        * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
        * @throws \Zend_Validate_Exception
        */
       public function addDataPrivacyAttribute()
       {
           $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();
           $eavSetup->addAttribute(
               \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
               'dataprivacy_attribute',
               [
                   'type' => 'varchar',
                   'label' => 'Data Privacy Status',
                   'input' => 'text',
                   'required' => 1,
                   'visible' => 1,
                   'user_defined' => 1,
                   'sort_order' => 999,
                   'position' => 999,
                   'system' => 0
               ]
           );

           $attributeSetId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Customer::ENTITY);
           $attributeGroupId = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Customer::ENTITY);

           $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'dataprivacy_attribute');
           $attribute->setData('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId);
           $attribute->setData('attribute_group_id', $attributeGroupId);

           $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
               'adminhtml_customer',
               'adminhtml_customer_address',
               'customer_account_edit',
               'customer_address_edit',
               'customer_register_address',
               'customer_account_create'
           ]);

           $this->attributeResource->save($attribute);
       }

       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public static function getDependencies()
       {
           return [];
       }

       /**
        *
        */
       public function revert()
       {
       }

       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public function getAliases()
       {
           return [];
       }
    }
   ```
2. After adding the above code to the given location please run the following command.

   - php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   - php bin/magento setup:di:compile
   - php bin/magento cache:flush